# How is it possible that photons can exist for 13 billion years?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

Implicit in the evidence of the Big Bang is the fact photons have
travelled for a period of time that is greater than 13,000,000,000
years. What special circumstance exists that would exempt photons
from the effects of entropy?

Comment: Why do photons need a 'special circumstance'? And why would entropy impact a photon?

Comment: Entropy is universal, hence an exemption (special circumstance no?) is needed. Why impact? If existential, then necessary. Since mass and energy are interchangeable and everything degrades over time photons should not be exempt, and should degrade over time. It is inconceivable that forces, or matter continue to exist unchanged in perpetuity while gravity, radiation etc. work upon said

Comment: How do 'gravity, radiation etc.' work on photons? Pay attention to annav's answer below. Be careful of human's idea of 'inconceivable' in physics - our intuitions are firmly rooted in the classical world.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment Jon.

Answer (score 6):

[Two photon interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) are very improbable. This is because it is a [quantum mechanical interaction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6126.pdf) and controlled by the electromagnetic coupling and the masses entering in the propagators of the charged virtual particles.

To get into a thermodynamic equilibrium (classical physics) a large number of scatters should exist so as to apply statistical mechanics, as with usual gases which scatter electromagnetically but their bulk behavior can be described thermodynamically.

The bulk of the photons  that have not interacted since decoupling  has come down  to us as cosmic microwave background .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It appears you addressed a specific case where my incredulity arises from the fact that I cannot allow myself to accept that it is possible for photons to travel for 13 billion years unaffected by entropy. No one has ever asserted or implied that photons have a half-life, or any limit on their durability. No energy exists for ever, no matter exists for ever. We use math to understand and deduce, but just as perpetual motion is impossible, so to are everlasting photons. Something is amis.

Comment: @GSE all elementary particles exist until they interact and then may change according to the quantum numbers of the interaction. It just happens that two photon interactions at low energies are effectively zero. It is worse for neutrinos with the weak interaction, that is why in order to see neutrinos a lot of mass   is needed in the detectors.  "no energy exists for ever"  in an inertial frame energy is conserved for ever. Entropy is a thermodynamic variable, photons are quantum entities and elementary particles.

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas . The primordial state of the mainstream cosmological model had the photon as a gas, i.e. in thermodynamic equilibrium and having temperature and pressure and black body characteristics, before decoupling,at 280000 years after Big Bang. After that the spectrum looses energy due to expansion although it keeps its black body shape. see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background .. My answer is for the time after decoupling, whenphotons no longer has gas properties because there are no interactions

Comment: Thank you for the kind and patient manner in which you are assisting me to understand your position. I believe that you are right, your perception is consistent with your training and education and that all of your colleagues are in agreement with what you have said here. I’ve read the information that your hyperlinks connect to. Perhaps if you can point out the fault in my conjecture

Comment: Sorry the prior paragraph was sent before completion accidentally.

Comment: Thank you for the kind and patient manner in which you have replied to my query. I clicked on both hyperlinks you provided and read all thaft is there. Despite quantum mechanics’ effective application and use, I cannot accept that photons or anything else for that matter, can exist essentially forever barring interaction. It appears analogous to using infinity in calculations. “Spooky” is

Comment: Sorry finger slipped on iPad, sent prematurely. Spooky is a good

Comment: Adjective. I will proceed to educate myself on the relevant issues to better comprehend the nuance and dynamics better. Perhaps with a new mind frame I can see the factors bearing upon the issues discussed in a new... LIGHT.

Comment: To model the "forever" I am talking about, that the standard model of particle physics predicts, a cosmological model should be constructed and there are several. Some see the universecontinually expanding and everything coming   to rest except,  the  very very low energy photons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe